# How to get prev() NOT just sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 buttons and only 4 of the buttons are next to each other. THere is one button that is in its own div. How can I access it with something like `prev()`?

Here is an example code:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" class="test" value="Test1">
  </div>

  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 2">
  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 3">
  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 4">
  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 5">
</div>

<script>
$(".test").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).prev().val();
  alert(value);
});
</script>
```

**Link:** https://jsfiddle.net/fzwqmyb4/3/

When i press "Test 4", it shows "Test 3" which is good. But when I press on button "Test 2", it should show "Test 1" but it does not. The reason is because `prev()` only works for siblings.

But how can I make a dynamic code that detects the previous of something even if its in another div?

Comment: How about if you use the html 'id' property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the previous element is an input or not, if no, find the child.
Check these code:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    var prevElement = $(this).prev().get(0);
    if(prevElement && prevElement.nodeName !== 'INPUT')
    {
      prevElement = $(prevElement).find('input').get(0);
    }

    var value = prevElement ? prevElement.value : '';
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`prev()` only finds the previous sibling. To find a nested element, you need to add some more logic to your function:

```js
$(".test").click(function() {
    var value;
    var prevTagName = $(this).prev().prop("tagName");
  
    switch(prevTagName)
    {
        case undefined:
            value = "no previous siblings";
            break;
            
        case "INPUT":
            value = $(this).prev().val();
            break;
            
        case "DIV":
            value = $(this).closest("div").find("input").val();
            break;
            
        default:
            value = "undefined";
            break;            
    }

    alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" class="test" value="Test1">
  </div>

  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 2">
  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 3">
  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 4">
  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 5">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using index, get the index of the current clicked element with the class test then subtract 1 to get the previous element with the same class

```js
$("input.test").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index()
  var prevval = $("input.test").eq(index - 1).val()

  console.log(prevval)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" class="test" value="Test1">
  </div>

  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 2">
  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 3">
  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 4">
  <input type="button" class="test" value="Test 5">
</div>
```